# ButtonGroup and ResourceEditor

Tags: java-me, radio-button, lwuit, resource-editor

We are trying to create an application using the LWUIT Resource Editor as much as possible, it's to say, avoiding creating the UI by code if we can.

We found out there is the possibility to assign a group to a `RadioButton` by setting the corresponding property on the Resource Editor tool.

So, as we need to implement some functionality for those radio buttons, how can we get the reference to that ButtonGroup instance that the `UIBuilder` has created (I suppose)?

And yes, considering we are using the Resource Editor tool to generate our midlets, the "custom" code is written on the `StateMachine` class.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK you can't get `ButtonGroup` from **ResourceEdit#GUI**. You can only possible to get `RadioButton` group name. But possible to add the `RadioButton` into `ButtonGroup` through your code. See the following code,

For calling `StateMachine()` constructor(use this code inside of constructor),

```
Form form = (Form) this.startApp(resources, null, true);
 RadioButton rb1 = this.findRadioButton(form);
 RadioButton rb = this.findRadioButton1(form);
 ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
 bg.add(rb);
 bg.add(rb1);
 bg.setSelected(0);
```

For calling `StateMachine(String resFile)` constructor(use this code inside of your MIDlet class),

```
 StateMachine sm = new StateMachine("/Sample.res");
 RadioButton rb1 = sm.findRadioButton(Display.getInstance().getCurrent());
 RadioButton rb = sm.findRadioButton1(Display.getInstance().getCurrent());
 ButtonGroup bg = new ButtonGroup();
 bg.add(rb);
 bg.add(rb1);
 bg.setSelected(0);
```

Comment: Well, what you wrote was our plan B, but it's interesting information. Thanks